# how fix Execution failed for task ':react-native-smart-splashscreen:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build.gradle, splash-screen

I use react-native-smart-splash-screen and install completely (do all task in docs).

and its work in the android emulator.

i install gradle-4-10-2 and in ./android folder in my project run this command **$>** **./gradlew assembleRelease** 
but get this erors:

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':react-native-smart-splashscreen:verifyReleaseResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

I use the react-native link but also not work

how can fix it and build .apk file

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, ensure [Generated Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html) . If error still exists, try add this line in your project `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```